# Syntax Problem with MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create procedure testproc
as
begin
select * from customers
end
```

In this code as is showing error. If I hover over as it shows as is not valid at this position. I have tried all other codes means different alternatives but still the same issue.

Comment: Please share the **exact** error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Here is the [MySQL docs page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) for creating a proc or function.

Comment: It's failing because you're using SQL Server syntax in a MySQL database. Read the documentation to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not passing in any parameters or processing the results, consider creating a view.  Like this:

```
USE `database_name`;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `v_my_view_name`
AS
    SELECT * FROM customers;
```

Then, you can call the view like this:

```
SELECT * FROM v_my_view_name;
```

Comment: No i am passing parameters it should work but why it shows error with 'as'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION testproc() RETURNS INT    
BEGIN
    DECLARE test INT;
    SELECT 42 INTO test; 
    RETURN test;
END
```

this `creates` a new `FUNCTION` named `testproc` returning the data type `INT`.
Between `BEGIN` and `END`, you find the body of the function which is executed each time you call the function.

- First we `DECLARE` a variable `test` of type `INT`.
- Then we start a query (`SELECT 42`) and store the result `INTO test`.
- Finally, we `RETURN test`.

To execute this function, you can use

```sql
SELECT testproc();
```

which will return 42.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

This the way I always do it:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testproc`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testproc()
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM customers;
END  //
DELIMITER ;
```

And to use this Stored Procedure

```
CALL testproc();
```